# Python module pexpect - how to connect to ssh server and then run bash commands

Tags: bash, ssh, spawn, pexpect

I'm new and I couldn't find a full answer to my question. So I'm asking it here.
I'm using python and the pexpect module to connect to an ssh server and run a few commands. However some of the commands don't work. I looked at the documentation and I can see that running a command like:

`ls -l | grep -i <Filter>`

Because I have to use the spawn command to run the bash script with a

`child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > logs.txt"')`

However, the way I connect to the server is by sending an ssh command with a key:

`p = pexpect.spawn("ssh  -t -t NAME@IP -i ~/.ssh/Keyfile ")`

So I can't run the spawn command with the bash command inside it (or can I?)

The response should be a password request because its re-directing me to another machine.

How do I use the spawn command so I can connect to the server with the key enter the password for the re-directed machine and then run a bash command.

**Note:** I'm trying to figure out the bash part. The Connection to the server and the re-direction + password insertion already work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send the command in the next line:

```
ssh = pexpect.spawn('ssh  -t -t NAME@IP -i ~/.ssh/Keyfile')
#You may write expect here to check if the ask if for password or some other error or the initial banner message
ssh.sendline('password')
#You may check if the password is successful
ssh.sendline('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > logs.txt"');
```

Comment: Thanks i dont know why this obvious solution did not come to me :)
Also note that i tried this on an android device too where there is no /bin/bash but rather bin/sh 
i had to state bin was located system so  the result would be 
**ssh.sendline('system/bin/sh -c "ls -l | grep LOG > logs.txt"');**

if anyone is intrested